# Curl Showing Unauthorized IBM Watson API

Tags: curl, ibm-watson, unauthorized, visual-recognition

My curl is showing unauthorized even though I put the API key and URL right. I used the service credential. I am asking about Watson's Visual Recognition in Anaconda Prompt.

`{"code":401, "error": "Unauthorized"}` is all I get

Answer (score 0):

The combination of endpoint and apikey that you are using is invalid. The apikey and url endpoint come in pairs. You can find the url for your instance at the same place you got your apikey.

If you can’t find your service url where you got your apikey then you have not obtained the apikey correctly.